# How can i remove the exact number of middle characters from a string?

Tags: string, python-3.x

I am trying to remove the number of middle characters in a string according to a given number. For example, if the string is `mahir` and I am told to remove one middle character, that would be `h` and the output would be `mair`, if the given number was 2, the output would have been `mar`.

I have worked out how the remove the middle characters but having troubles in removing it correctly. This is my code:

```
remover = int(input())
s = "mahir"
counter = len(s) - remover
while True:
   h = len(s)//2
   mod = (len(s) + 1) % 2
   s = s[:h - mod] + s[h + 1:]
   if len(s) == counter:
       break
print(s)
```

If i enter `remover` more than one I end up getting an inifinte loop. How can i fix this and remove the correct number of middle characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice the string like this:

```
s = 'mahir'
n = int(input())
i = (len(s) - n + 1) // 2
print(s[:i] + s[i + n:])
```